# Split one file into multiple files based on pattern with awk

Tags: bash, awk, split

I have a binary file with the following format:

> file
> 04550525023506346054(....)6464563463634634634436346**8badcafe**268664363463463463463463463464647(....)47401749741742**8badcafe**34376362623626(....)262

and I need to split it in multiple files (using awk) that look like this:

> file1
> 045505250235063460546464563463634634634436346
>
> file2
>
> **8badcafe**26866436346346346346346346346464747401749741742
>
> file3
>
> **8badcafe**34376362623626262

I have found on stackoverflow the following line:

> cat file |
> awk -v RS="\x8b\xad\xca\xfe" 'NR > 1 { print RS $0 > "file" (NR-1); close("file" (NR-1)) }'

and it works for all the files but the first.
Indeed, the file I called file1, is not created because it does not start with the eye catcher 8badcafe.
How can I fix the previous command line in order to have the output I need?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
awk '{gsub(/8badcafe/,"\n&");num=split($0, a,"\n");for(i=1;i<=num;i++){print a[i] > "file"++e}}'  Input_file
```

Substituting the string "8badcafe" to a new line and string's value. Then splitting the current line into an array named a whose field separator is new line. then traversing through the array a's all values and printing them one by one into the file1, file2.... with "file" and a increasing count variable named e.

Output files as follows:

```
cat file1
045505250235063460546464563463634634634436346
cat file2
8badcafe26866436346346346346346346346464747401749741742
cat file3
8badcafe34376362623626262
```

Comment: It does not seems to work... file2 does not start with 8badcafe

Comment: It's working fine for me, I edited my answer with output files too now.

Comment: Maybe I have to specify that the file I reported above it's just an example of the format... my original file is much bigger. If I run your line I get more than 10000 files and, as I said, the second file does not start with 8badcafe.

Comment: Could you please update your question, with proper examples and samples so that we could try to help you.

Comment: I have already updated the question specifying that is just an example of the format... I need to work with files bigger than 1GB so I can't put one file as example but I think that the sample is ok. I have this binary file where the "string" 8badcafe is repeated more times and I have to split this file in multiple files which start with 8badcafe (with the exception of the first)